# How do i draw depth complexity(overdraw) in directx 11?

Tags: directx11

I want to read the stencil value in the shader so I can set colors for different depths.

What I understand. Make a loop after the scene is rendered but before is is presented.
so a loop with the number of colors(k) and in the loop, use the code:

```
 md3dImmediateContext->OMSetDepthStencilState(RenderStates::DrawDepthDSS, k);
```

This is what I know. What are the other steps? like to send the depth to the shader?

..I have this code for the shader

```
   Texture2D<uint> txStencil : register (t0); // set the corresponding register
float4 PSStencil(float4 pos: SV_Position) : SV_Target
{
    uint stencil = txStencil.Load(int3(pos.xy, 0));

    // debug output
    if (stencil == 1) return float4(0, 1, 0, 1);
    else return float4(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

But how do I send the shader the stencil value?

Comment: As an alternative to my answer regarding the stencil buffer, you could just use pos.Z as an approximate gauge for depth. Screen depth is 0-1 so you could divide that into however many portions you need with each sub-range representing a layer.

Answer (score 1):

1. Clear the stencil to 0, set it to always pass, and increment for passes and z-fails.
2. Draw scene to offscreen target. (are you only outputting solid colors based on stencil?)
3. The stencil is now filled with the number of times the GPU tried to shade each pixel
   a. Discard color buffer??
4. Set the stencil to decrement only on passes and only pass when stencil is >0. The last stencil values to reach 0 will be the "top layer" so we need to render them in reverse order.
5. Activate the appropriate "layer-shader" (or update a color value in a constant buffer)
6. Draw a fullscreen quad. Pixels that have stencil >0 will be filled with the color and the stencil value decremented for each.
7. Activate the (bottom - 1) layer-shader (or update the color in a constant buffer)
8. ...
9. Lastly, activate the top-most layer shader (or update the color in a constant buffer)
10. Draw a fullscreen quad. Pixels that have stencil >0 will...

You could draw the quad instanced and supply a per-instance color and/or use the SV_InstanceID semantic to index into an array of colors. Each instance represents a layer and you can render every layer with one DrawInstanced(...) call.

**Edit:**
Misread part of your question. The second parameter of OMSetDepthStencilState() sets a constant value used for comparison. You can set up DrawDepthDSS to only render pixels whose stencil value exactly matches the parameter, using the layer's 1-based index as the second parameter.

```
stencilFunction = GREATER; //Member of DrawDepthDSS
OMSetDepthStencilState(..., 5); //Render only stencil>5 pixels
stencilFunction = EQUAL; //Member of DrawDepthDSS
OMSetDepthStencilState(..., 1); //Render only stencil=1 pixels (top layer)
OMSetDepthStencilState(..., 10); //Render only stencil=10 pixels (9 layers deep)
```

IIRC, the default function is ALWAYS and the parameter is ignored. The source of the color is arbitrary. As it is written, you appear to be copying the depth/stencil buffer and then wanting to sample it. Needing or wanting to do so usually indicates a wrong turn somewhere along the way. Please consider the usage I've presented; the stencil is good at counting up and down, so I make it count up, then down. I tell it what to do and don't ask it for anything.